# Uploading videos by other people on your channel via site

Tags: youtube

I want users to send their videos on my YT channel via my site. 
It worked last year but now Youtube requests users to be authenticated on Youtube.

If it even possible now?

Here is the code:

```
public function getPostParams()
   {

        $header = array(
            "alg" => "RS256",
            "typ"  => "JWT"
        );

        $jwt = array(
            "iss" => "gulliapp@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
            "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
            "aud" => "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "exp" => time() + 3600,
            "iat" => time()
        );

        $jwt_string = JWT::encode($jwt, null, 'RS256', "52e47342c1d175e88a94e0076e7a87474013a798", $header);    

        $headers = array( 
           "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
       );

       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3000); 
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       $post = "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=" . $jwt_string ;
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
       $res = curl_exec($ch);
       $url = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $token = json_decode($res);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $token->access_token;

   }

   public function saveFile($file, $name, $description, $token)
   {

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId(self::$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
        $client->setClientSecret(self::$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
        $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
        $redirect = filter_var('http://gulli.ru/videocontest/add/',  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
        $client->setAccessToken($token);
        $client->setAccessType("offline");

        $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
          try{
            $videoPath = $file['tmp_name'];

            $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
            $snippet->setTitle("web2016");
            $snippet->setDescription("web2016");
            $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

            $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

            $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
            $status->privacyStatus = "private";

            // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
            $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
            $video->setSnippet($snippet);
            $video->setStatus($status);

            $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

            $client->setDefer(true);

            $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

            $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
                $client,
                $insertRequest,
                'video/*',
                null,
                true,
                $chunkSizeBytes
            );
            $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


            $status = false;
            $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
            while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
              $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
              $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
            }

            fclose($handle);

            $client->setDefer(false);

          } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
            $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
                htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
          } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
            $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
                htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
          }

          $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

        }

       return false;
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add a [mcve]! We need more info about what you're trying to do. Please provide some source code, how you're uploading videos currently.

Comment: Added the code. Thank you!